# can't get child element to change text color on hover when using opaque background

Tags: html, css, menu, opacity

I've made what should be a simple CSS menu, with a drop-down.
When the drop-down is visible, I want it and its parent element to have a partially opaque background, and to change the text color to a dark color.
The child UL does what it's supposed to do, but the parent does not.
It looks to me like the text is getting covered by the background opacity of the parent.

I want it to look something like this:
[image]

but instead it looks like this on hover:
[image]

How can I make the parent object "PORTFOLIO" dark colored with a partially opaque background on hover?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s36njjtt/)

```
<div id="navigation">

<ul id='mainNav'>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
   <li class='hasSub'><a href='#' id='portfolioLink'>PORTFOLIO</a>
      <ul class='subMenu'>
         <li><a href='#'>AUTOMOTIVE</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>COMMERCIAL</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>DISTRIBUTION</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>MANUFACTURING</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>MULTI-TENNANT</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>MUNICIPAL</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>UNDER CONSTRUCTION</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>SERVICES</a></li>   

</ul>
</div>

body{
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:16pt;
}


#navigation{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background:#ff5200;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

.subMenu{
    display:none;
}

#navigation > ul > li > a { 
  font-size: .6em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#navigation > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  align:center;
}

#navigation > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #dddddd;
}

.hasSub:hover{
     background: url("img/75%-transparent-white.png");
     background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);     
}       

.hasSub:hover a{
    color: #495c5e;
}

.hasSub:hover > .subMenu {
        display: block;
        position:absolute;
    margin-left:-40px;
}

.subMenu{
    list-style-type:none;   
}

.subMenu li{    
  background: url("img/75%-transparent-white.png");
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75)  
}

.subMenu li > a{    
    font-size:.6em;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.subMenu li > a:hover{  
    color:#ff5200;  
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is specificity.

```
#navigation > ul > li:hover > a
```

Is more specific than

```
.hasSub:hover a
```

So the former is overriding the latter despite their source order, and .hasSub is getting the same color as the standard menu items.

You could solve it by changing

```
.hasSub:hover a{
    color: #495c5e;
}
```

into

```
#navigation > ul li.hasSub:hover a{
    color: #495c5e;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are setting the portfolio menu to light gray when on hover. Just set a darker color such as black to it.

```
#navigation > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #000000;
}
```